# Can components / non-plugins react to events?

Tags: component, development, plugin

Is it possible for components to react to events - i.e. in some way become an observer to plugin events?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is No. By default, when a trigger is executed by only the associated plug-in observers are going to be executed.

However, you could create your own system plugin to propagate the event into your component observer. Be aware, that every new event broadcast adds a new executing step, just to reach a deeper level.

Comment: Too bad... might need to look into a custom implementation...